# jQuery: tinycarousel with modification - Overlay is sometimes too late (Whatch the fiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, slider, slideshow

I have the tinycarousel and I put an overlay over it. I want to show text in this overlay every time, the move-function is over. When it switches automatically, the overlay is showhn correct everytime
But when I switch between the pager numbers at the bottom of the slide too fast, sometimes the overlay is too late faded in.

-----> [Here is my fiddle to the code below (http://jsfiddle.net/5xMNx/)](http://jsfiddle.net/5xMNx/) <-----

```
$('#slider-code').tinycarousel({ 
pager: true,
interval: true, 
duration: 1500,
intervaltime: 10000,
callback: function(element, index){
    $( ".textbox" ).each(function( index ) {
        $( this ).hide();
    });

    var value = $('ul li').eq(index).attr('tag');
    console.log(value);
         $('#'+value).fadeIn("slow").delay(7500);
        $('#'+value).fadeOut("slow");
    }

});

});
```

Has anyone an idea how I can make it right? THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your code, I'm not sure of what you really wanted so ask me if something goes wrong.

Here is the demo : [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WM8ue/)

**What I've changed :**

I used a javascript `setTimeout` method instead of `.delay()`. This will allow you to reset the timeout with the `clearTimeout` method : [JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Like that :

```
timeout = setTimeout(function(){ //init the timer
              $('#'+value).fadeOut("slow"); 
          },7500);
```

And you can reset it when you need with :

```
clearTimeout(timeout); //reset the timer
```

See JQuery's `.delay()` doc :

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

I've also used the JQuery `.stop` method ([doc here](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)) the stop the currently running animation before launching a new one, which may be still running if you click very fast on different slider pages.

I used it like that :

```
$('#'+value).stop().fadeIn("slow");
```

Hope I helped you !

Comment: Really really cool!! I think its almost the solution I want. But do you have the same problem now, that when you switch between the pager very fast, that the text sometimes is faded out too fast and the next animation started just a few seconds after the fadeout?

Comment: Yes, I see the problem. I tried to fix it but I think your code needs to be structured differently ! btw I saw that when you hover the carousel, it stops sliding, but the text still fade out after 7s, is that what you want ?? It can be easily fixed :)

Comment: I tried to fix the "fade out too fast" problem, and I also fixed when you click on the `li` of the already shown slide, it shouldn't fadeIn and fadeOut the same textBox anymore ;)
Tell me if it's better for you : [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/D4BAP/)

Comment: Yes man! Really great! Now I only must clear the function, that the fade out doesn't fadout, when the hover is active! But when the hover is inactive, it has to fadeout immediatly when the next slide begins. Than it would be really perfect! Do you have a solution for this? Because you said that it coul be fixed easily :-)

Comment: Indeed it can be fixed easily, the only problem is that tinycarousel only callback is when the animation is finished, and not when it begins, so we won't be able to make it fade out when beginning sliding. I don't know if this is important for your project, but I think that's still better than before :) see : [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rXT3m/)

Comment: Yes, would be cool if there would be a listener or a function which said beforemove or something! But now it's really perfect for me! THANK YOU SO MUCH! You saved my day :-)